# Как работают даты в телеграмме(tdl)?

Tags: node.js, telegram, tdlib

Сейчас практикую разработку клиента на [TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib) и использую nodejs с библиотекой [tdl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tdl#api)

У меня есть два вопроса на которые я самостоятельно не смог найти ответа.

1. Как работают даты в TDLib? Мне нужно выводить текстом сколько минут назад происходило какое-то действия, например сколько минут назад было отправлено сообщение. Когда я получаю любую дату в tdl, то мне выдаёт цифру например `1674385280`, кажется, что все просто и стоит просто использовать небольшую формулу для вычисления как раз таки минут, но проблема в том, что эта дата слишком маленькая. На момент написания этого вопроса дата у меня выдаёт следующее `1674392437485`, если попробовать отнять дату из сообщения от моей текущей, то выдаст огромную цифру `1672718052205` и работать с ней просто не возможно, пытаешься разделить на `60000` чтобы получить например минуты и получаешь ещё одну космо-цифру `27878634.203416668`, хотелось бы узнать как правильно работать с такими датами.
2. Каким образом можно превратить файл `.tgs` в формат `.gif` или `.webp`, немного лазил по интернету и нашел лишь несколько библиотек который работают через CLI интерфейс. Есть ли возможно какой-то пакет или способ попроще конвертировать формат файла?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден только на первый вопрос.
Решение очень простое, умножить число на `1000`.